# How do you include a picture on the home page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a simple website using MVC-4 (my first). I would like to include a picture on the entire background of the home page. How do I do it? Where do I go? What's the code?

Comment: Look into css and backgrounds on google

Comment: Thanks, T I for your respectful answer. I did this as a test to see how many here voted down the question instead of helping someone who is new to programming.

Comment: The community is generally more then happy to help provided the question shows research effort and a clear example of the problem. Please read the faq.

Comment: Bhasyakarulu was more than helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding following css code within the `<head> </head>` tag of Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml

```
<style>
body  {
    background-image: url('yourimage.gif');
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, Bhasyakarulu.

Comment: You are welcome. @NelsonVillegas If it works, would you mind marking as answered.

Comment: No problem, Bhasyakarulu.